# Parameters pass by reference in function

Tags: php, com, xampp

i need to pass parameter pass by reference , how can i do

```
$obj = new COM("zkemkeeper.zkem.1"); 
$isconnect=$obj->Connect_Net('192.168.10.91',4370);
if($isconnect==true){
$obj->GetDeviceTime(1,&$year,&$month,&$day,&$hour,&$minter,&$second);
}
```

it give error , i am using xampp php version 7.2.6 
i have also uncomment allow_call_time_pass_reference=on in php.ini

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php
>   on line 40

Comment: `allow_call_time_pass_reference` hasn't done anything since PHP 5.4. Whether variables are passed by reference or not is decided by the function declaration (`GetDeviceTime`), not the call.

Comment: So what happens if you remove all the `&` ?? Normally the function itself defines the need for pass by reference, you dont have to do anything but pass variables.

Comment: not working, actually i am using method from dll

Comment: _Not working??_ Thats not a helpfull error message. Can you tell us what the actual error message says

Comment: Its also useful if you tell us which line is line 40 when you do show the error message. Specially when you only show us 5 lines of code

Comment: sorry for wasting your time, now its work, thanks alot

Comment: So what did you do to fix it? You can provide your own answer if it will help others

Comment: i have remove "&" from parameters,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the function itself defines the need for pass by reference, you dont have to do anything but pass variables.

So try

```
$obj->GetDeviceTime(1,$year,$month,$day,$hour,$minter,$second);
```